# Rotating tables not working with {sidewaystable}

Tags: tables, rotating

My intention is to rotate a table which is to wide. 
Coded in .cls:

```
\usepackage{rotating}
```

I [work in this document (ch.2)](https://es.sharelatex.com/project/5847e1b0e473d1cf1e4aee56) (feel free to enter and edit it), which is adapted from the Harvard-thesis template, hosted [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/dissertate.io/Dissertate-Harvard-LaTeX.zip).

Sample table:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Triangulación de técnicas utilizadas}
\label{tab:tecnicas}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\toprule[1.5pt]
\bf Producto & \bf Componentes & \bf Técnicas & \bf Herramientas\\
\midrule
 Twitteresfera & Tweets & Framing & Google Spreadshets \\
  & & Network Agenda Setting  & ?\\
  & & Social Network Analysis & Gephi \\
  & & Natural Language Processing &  \\
  & & Quadratic Assignment Procedure & ? \\
  &  & Entrevistas & Transcripciones & Grounded Theory & Libreoffice, Nvivo\\
   & & Entevista cualitativa & Nvivo\\
  Producción bibliográfica & Libros y artículos & Sistematized Review & Zotero, Mendeley\\
  Producción no bibliográfica & Webs, videos, otros & Netnografía & Navegadores\\

\bottomrule[1.25pt]
\end {tabular}\par
\caption*{}
\end{table}

\end{sidewaystable}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, if I understood your question correct.

I think, to get it work, you'll just need to get rid of the `\begin{table} ... \end{table}` lines (as well as the second `\caption` line.

I had to load package booktabs, but then LaTeX run without an error message and produced an document with an rotated table.

```
\begin{sidewaystable}

\centering
\caption{Triangulación de técnicas utilizadas}
\label{tab:tecnicas}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\toprule[1.5pt]
\textbf{ Producto} & \textbf{ Componentes} & \textbf{ Técnicas} & \textbf{ Herramientas}\\
\midrule
  Twitteresfera & Tweets & Framing & Google Spreadshets \\
  & & Network Agenda Setting  & ?\\
  & & Social Network Analysis & Gephi \\
  & & Natural Language Processing &  \\
  & & Quadratic Assignment Procedure & ? \\
  &  & Entrevistas & Transcripciones \\
  & Grounded Theory & Libreoffice, Nvivo\\
  & & Entevista cualitativa & Nvivo\\
Producción bibliográfica & Libros y artículos & Sistematized Review & Zotero, Mendeley\\
Producción no bibliográfica & Webs, videos, otros & Netnografía & Navegadores\\

\bottomrule[1.25pt]
\end {tabular}\par
\end{sidewaystable}
```

(And there was one `\\` missing in your document.

Hope it also works to you.

Bye

Jan